# Postgresql : merge rows of json key-value into one flat dict (not an array)

Tags: postgresql, query, json, syntax

In Postgresql, I want to build a flat JSON "dict" out of returned rows of key/values

When I call :

```
select json_agg( jsonb_build_object(key, COALESCE(value,'')) ) from props;
```

I get spurious braces around the pairs:

```
 [{"email": "jeremie@example.com"}, {"phone": "0222222222"}, {"sex": "male"}]
```

I would like to get this flattened like this instead:

```
 {"email": "jeremie@example.com", "phone": "0222222222", "sex": "male"}
```

How shall I write the query ? (there are no conflicts on keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have unique keys, you can use `jsonb_object_agg()`

```
select jsonb_object_agg(key, COALESCE(value,''))
from props;
```

Comment: How simple ! Looks like I am too much trying to use sql and only then json fonctions !